# Translating choice lists in LightSwitch

Tags: localization, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to translate the display name of choice list items defined for LightSwitch entity properties?

I would like to be able to show different users translated display names in their language when they are viewing the SAME record, and also show translated names in the autocomplete combo box when they are editing a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. The values are stored in the *LSML* file & aren't able to be modified at runtime. If you need to translate the values, then you'll need to use a lookup table (possibly by using a custom RIA service) instead of a *Choice List*.

The advantage of a *Choice List* is that it's very quick & easy to set one up.

The down side of a *Choice List* is the lack of flexibility, or even reusability (you have to define the values for the list every time you want to use it somewhere).